# How to mock Typeorm DataSource with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, typeorm

Im new to using typeorm and Jest for that matter. I have a function that is creating and returning a DataSource here:

app/lib/connections/createDBConnection.ts

```
 const createDBConnection = async () => {
  const dbUrl = Environment.get('DATABASE_URL')
  const db = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    url: dbUrl,
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [],
    connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
  })
  await db.initialize()
  return db
}

export default createDBConnection
```

Here is the get function if it helps:

```
export class Environment {
  public static get(key: string): string {
    const result = process.env[key]

    if (result === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to find key ${key} in environment`)
    }

    return result
  }
```

Here is my test file:

```
const FakeDB = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: 'fakeURL',
  synchronize: false,
  entities: [],
  connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
})

jest.mock('app/lib/connections/createDBConnection', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(FakeDB))
}
)

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks()
})

test('creates a fake connection', async () => {
  const DbConnection = await createDBConnection()
  expect(DbConnection).toBeTruthy()
  expect(DbConnection).toBeInstanceOf(DataSource)
  expect(DbConnection).toEqual(FakeDB)
  
  // Im trying to make something like these pass
  expect(FakeDB.initialize).toHaveBeenCalled
  expect(FakeDB.isInitialized).toBe(true)
})
```

Im not sure how to mock out the initialize function correctly. I want to verify its called in my function somehow. The first three assertions seem to pass, but im not sure if its actually correct, since those bottom 2 both fail. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Ive tried mocking the initialize a couple of ways like:

```
 jest.mock('typeorm'), () => {
   return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
     return {
       initialize: () => {true}
   }
 })
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you are mocking TypeORM which you shouldn't. You should trust [the API](https://typeorm.io/data-source-api) and that TypeORM will return an instance of `DataSource` and that it sets `isInitialized=true`.

What you might do is to mock `createDBConnection` in the components that are consuming it, or maybe design your code with [dependency injection (DI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) so you can inject your `DataSource` instance in your application, or its double when testing.

And, if you still want to test that your `createDBConnection` is working as expected, you may assert that `Environment.get` is called with `DATABASE_URL` and that `db.initialize()` is called:

```
const mockDS = {
  initialize: jest.fn(),
};

jest.mock("typeorm", () => {
  return {
    DataSource: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockDS),
  };
});

// Env
const mockEnv = {
  get: jest.fn(),
};
jest.mock("src/path/to/environment/file", () => {
  return {
    Environment: mockEnv,
  };
});

import createDBConnection from "src/app/lib/connections/createDBConnection.ts";

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

test("calls .initialize() and env.get", async () => {
  await createDBConnection();

  expect(mockEnv.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("DATABASE_URL");
  expect(mockDS.initialize).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```